# Stuck in GRUB Rescue Mode, all partitions -> "Unknown filesystem"

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I somehow messed up my laptop... I have a dual boot machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7. The Ubuntu OS has been installed a couple of days ago and I was encountering an annoying bug: when booting on ubuntu i got the **"Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /"** message.

I dealt with it by editing the GRUB2 boot entry:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=AAC884AC1F144321 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

from "**ro**" to "**rw**"

It worked, but when i booted one day later i got into GRUB rescue mode with message:
"**unknown file system**"

"**ls**" command gives me the 4 partitions, but they're all msdos:

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

when i try to use "**ls**" with any of the partitions above to locate the GRUB modules i always get '**unknown filesystem**':

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos6)
(hd0,msdos6): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)
(hd0,msdos6): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos2)
(hd0,msdos6): Filesystem is unknown
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)
(hd0,msdos6): Filesystem is unknown
```

Booting from USB is not an option because the USB drive doesn't even appear in the boot menu options (and yes, i'm sure it's bootable). What's wrong? System Diagnostics says the memory is fine and the Primary Hard Disk Self Test runs fine for the short test but freezes at 8% for the long one.

System recovery just gets me again in the GRUB rescue mode. Please help, I'm not a very experienced user and this is the first time I have to deal with this kind of issue.